# Oracle APEX comma alternatives in Text Field

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, textfield

Im working with **Oracle Application Express (APEX)**. I have a page with a link and a page with a Text Field (in simple terms). When i click on that link, a JavaScript function puts a coordinate to the second page with the Text Field. The coordinates should appear in that Text Field. The point is: They really appear, but only a part of them. I can show you that:

This should appear in the Text Field:

```
LatLng(48.30247, 16.02837)
```

But the Text Field shows only this:

```
LatLng(48.30247
```

I realised the problem: Apex thinks, that it should stop writing something in a Text Field, when there is a "**,**" (comma). But I need that "**,**" for my Database. So my question: Is there another way to write the comma? Or can I tell Apex to not do anything when a comma appears?

Comment: How exactly are you passing your values?

Comment: With this function: `function paste_coord(){
window.location = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:202:&APP_SESSION.::NO::P202_Text_Field:' + popup_coord;

}` When I look into the link in my browser on the new page, I see `P202_TEXT_FIELD:LatLng(48.30247,%2016.02837)` so that should be right. The **popup_coord** is my string where the coordinates are stored.

Comment: Hi, shouldn't be: P202_TEXT_FIELD:'LatLng(48.30247,%2016.02837)' ?

Comment: @Typo I don't think so - but I'm not sure. I don't know what to type in, to look like this :\ I can't type `' ' ' + popup_coord + ' ' '` :D Or do you mean it should look like this in the link, to work?

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in an Apex URI are colon separated, but multi-value parameters, such as lists of page items to set, are comma separated. Apex thinks you are trying to set the value of P202_TEXT_FIELD to "LatLng(48.30247" and the value of a second, unspecified page item to ", 16.02837)".

You can escape commas in an Apex URI by enclosing the value in backslashes, ie:

```
"\"+popup_coord+"\"
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have had a brain burp - I've corrected my answer. Ideally  you wouldn't pass string values in the URL anyway, but enclosing in backslashes should work.

Comment: The two backslash ("\") "destroy" my function(not working). To ensure, that thats the problem I tried `popup_coord2 = "\"+popup_coord+"\";`. Thats not working as in the link(i tried it in the link). So I tried out `popup_coord2 = "test"+popup_coord+"test";` and that works. Or did I do something wrong with your code? :\